# Can't open Sage math Jupyer notebook on Mac : Safari can't connect to localhost server

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, localhost, sage

I have to use SageMath for my studies and I'm annoyed because I can't open it anymore. I usually just click on "Jupyter notebook from folder" on my SageMath 9.3 [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7BOu.png) and then it used to open a Jupyter notebook in the navigator and it worked fine but now I get this error

[image: 1]

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall SageMath 9.3 (I use a MacBook Air from 2017), I restarted my computer, I tried different navigators, I checked the firewall and it was  off.

What is wrong ? How do I fix it ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem last week.  I had `Sage 9-7`.  I installed `Sage 9-8` from `3-manifolds` (link below) and it fixed it.

https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases

Comment: *Provide context for links*: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.